# getimagesize function is not working properly

Tags: php, html, css

I created a function, i am using this function to resize image to make it fit as div background image, i send div size and image path to function.. It works well when height is bigger than width but it does not work when width is bigger than height.. How can this be possible?

```
function imgw($divsize, $imgw){
$imgurl=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$imgw;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgw);
if($width > $height){$nwidth="auto";}
if($width < $height){$nwidth=$divsize."px";}
if($width==$height){$nwidth=$divsize."px";}
return $nwidth;
}

function imgh($divsize, $imgh){
$imgurl=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/".$imgh;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgurl);
if($width > $height){$nheight=$divsize."px";}
if($width < $height){$nheight="auto";}
if($width==$height){$nheight=$divsize."px";}
return $nheight;
}
```

Edit: This functions are used for the following code below.

```
<? $anwidth=imgw(70, $solsutunpic); $anheight=imgh(70, $solsutunpic);?>
<div style='background: url(<?php echo $solsutunpic ?>) no-repeat; background-size: <?php echo $anwidth ?> <?php echo $anheight ?>; width: 70px; height: 70px; display:inline-block; border-radius: 3px; margin-right:5px;'></div>
```

Comment: how does "list($,$) = getimagesize($)" work? it seems your setting a function call with another function call.. unfamiliar to me.. and also what is ' $divsize."px" ' (the period before "px")?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done with css only. Can you provide more details on what exactly you want to happen, and may be some html code.

Comment: I added how and for what i am using the functions.. As i said it works fine when height is bigger than width but not the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in function imgw($divsize, $imgw)

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgw);
```

right code

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgurl);
```

Comment: Sometimes working so many hours is not good! :) I lost nearly 2 hours to find this basic thing out.. Thanks.